# Possible tag merge: table, matrix, array

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

These related tags are not well distinguished (if at all) in their application: **[table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table), [matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix), [array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array)**.
A number of questions are double tagged with these, and a brief review suggests little consistency in how they are used.  There is also the **[tensor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensor)** tag which unlike these has a full *tag wiki*.

We need clear guidelines for how these tags should be used, or they should be merged.  Possibly some should be subsumed into **[tensor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensor)**.  Please answer with your recommended resolution to this situation, including proposed *tag wikis* for any tags that you believe should be kept.

Comment: [tag:data] is another very closely related tag, without a tag wiki, that is used quite often.

Comment: It seems Szabolcs answer was quite appreciated, but I feel we should at least add tag wikis for [tag:data], [tag:table] and [tag:array]. How can we move forward?

Comment: An interesting successful case from math.se is [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/lets-blacklist-the-graph-tag). Maybe we should remove the [tag:table] and [tag:array] tags and make substitutes.

Comment: We should probably use the same technique (maybe blacklisting, as mentioned) to disambiguate [tag:editing] here on meta. editing can mean formatting, as in [editing-help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), as well as editing other peoples questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that all of these should be merged.

- **matrix:**  I noticed that this is often used when [linear-algebra](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) would be just as appropriate, or even more appropriate (e.g. eigenvalue-related questions).  It can't be merged with [linear-algebra](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) though because sometimes it's used in questions about on-screen formatting of matrices or matrix construction, not linear algebra operations.

  So, to sum up: "matrix" is an array in the context of linear algebra and mathematics.

  Likewise, a tensor is a mathematical concept, and a tensor-related question might be about tensor products, tensor contraction, etc.
- **array:** This will come up in a programming/CS context.  An array is a data structure and we talk about it in a computer science context, e.g. when discussing that in a loop Sow/Reap is more efficient than AppendTo because it avoids quadratic complexity.
- **table:**  Looking at its usage, this appears to be the least consistent of the three.  Sometimes the question just uses `Table`, quite often it's about table generation, sometimes about handling file formats (CSV, tab separated, etc.) and sometimes about formatting ([grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) could replace it in that case).

Personally, this is my opinion:

- A hard no on merging [matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix).  This is a huge tag and renaming it would create lots of confusingly tagged question. Also the distinction is pretty clear as it's used (should be used?) in a math context, so I wouldn't merge other tags *into* this one either.
- About [array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) and [table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table): I don't have a hard opinion, just a slight worry that renaming either would again create too many confusingly tagged questions, unless someone goes through all of them and verifies that the tags are appropriate.  If a merge happens, I think it should be `array -> table` and not vice versa, as `table` is more general.  But then `table` usually refers to 2D (or 1D) structures while array can be anything.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to this.  All that seems pretty reasonable.  Do you *recommend* any change from the existing structure?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The main thing I wanted to say: please don't change `matrix`.  Other than that, no.  (While I do recognize the problems.)

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, +1. But personally I think [tag:array] is more general than [tag:table]. The impression I get is that people generally only tag with [tag:table] when the question concerns `Table`, and I don't think it's very useful to tag according to function in this case. Okay, `Table` could (in principle) produce a ragged array, but it's not really meant for that and to do so is something of a hack.

Comment: @OleksandrR. `Array[If[# < #2, 0, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]] &, {3, 3}]` is also ragged. Maybe we should preserve all the tags. I think that how table is used in practice is not too bad. Suppose you have a list `{{name,weight},{john, 60},{mary, 50}}`. Questions about such objects could be tagged table, the object is 2D, not packed and at some point we probably want to display it using `TableForm` or something. If you import an excel sheet, chances are the resulting 2D list is a table in this sense. The main thing that we should set straight would be to disallow tagging as table for use of Table.

Comment: Alternatively I like the idea of table being a relatively uninformative and low quality tag. Anything involving a possibly ragged list of lists with elements occurring at a fixed depth that can be anything, or anything that is displayed like this, like [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41834/4330) could then be called table. More experienced users could then maybe retag.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom my point was that [tag:table] mostly means `Table`, but [tag:array] doesn't necessarily have anything to do with `Array`. Also, a ragged array is still an array, even if it's not what people usually first think of when they see the term. To call it a ragged table will probably not be understood.

Answer (score 1):

*I had deleted this answer shortly after posting it. At the time I felt my suggestion for the description of table was a bit convoluted. However I still think that keeping low quality tags that are very general is an option that should be taken seriously, so I have undeleted my answer. When reading it please do not bother yourself too much with the details.*

---

**Introduction**

I agree with Szabolcs points. In fact, I am in favour of preserving all the tags.

I feel the word table in the context of Mathematica is a bit ambiguous. On one hand, we have the meaning of table as a 2D sheet of information to be read or even altered by humans. On the other, we have the meaning that comes from the function `Table`. This is the main motivation for my suggestion.

### Suggestion

*I have written this in such a way that we can vote for it. More motivation, examples and considerations are further below. Please disregard these in voting.*

**Concept table**

*This information could be added to the /info page of [table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table)*

We understand under a table an expression that is either the result of a typical use of `Table`, or an expression that looks like a 2D list and which is meant to be displayed, for example using `TableForm`. An example of the latter kind of expression would be `{{name,weight},{john, 60},{mary, 50}}`, which is not an expression typically generated by `Table`.

Questions that should be tagged with [table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table) are questions in which a table plays a central role, or the use of the function `Table` plays a central role.

It is acceptable to tag questions about fine tuned formatting of a table with [table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table), even though it is preferable to (re)tag such questions with [grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid).

If the question is about data structures, the tag [array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) is preferred.

If the question is not about the generation of a table, but rather the use of it, it may be preferable to tag as [matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) or [tensor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensor). Do this in case the table is in fact a matrix/tensor and built-in functions that deal specifically with such expressions (like Dot) are used.

**Tag wiki (description) table**

Tag questions in which either 1) the function `Table` plays a central role, 2) a nested list plays a central role or 3) a two dimensional expression that is meant to be displayed, for example using TableForm, plays a central role.

**Examples table**

An example of a question where the use of `Table` plays a central role would be [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37954/4330) and maybe even [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19334/4330) (even though `ParallelTable` is used instead of `Table`). Especially because the idiom `If[cond, return, Sequence@@{}]` is used, where `Sequence@@{}` is equivalent to Mr.Wizards vanishing function. This shows that `Table` is more flexible than one might think.

[this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41834/4330) is an example of a question in which  a central role is played by an extreme of the set of expressions that the description of table above encompasses.

More examples where the use of `Table` could be nontrivial is where the side effects of `Table` are important, or when we want to use `Table` inside `Compile`.

**Tag wiki (description) array**

This tag is **reserved** for questions about the data structure array. Simply using the function Array does not justify using this tag.

*Note: Unfortunately, I am not sure if tag wikis can be bold*

**Motivation**

The reason to make the tag [table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table) encompass a broad class of expressions is to avoid mistagging. To see that mistagging is a problem, think about how many times the tag bugs is incorrectly used. One reason to make [table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table) a general tag and [array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array) a more specific tag, is that `Table` is used much more often than `Array`, and consequently [table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table) is used more often than [array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array). This is convenient, as array is also the name of the [Array data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure), which is an important concept IMO.

**Considerations**

We should probably also provide text for the /info page of [array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array). This should especially make clear that [table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table) can be used as an alternative.

I would suggest also writing the word reserved in the tag wiki (description) of [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) in bold (if this is possible).